# Using PowerShell to compare and copy files of a certain type recursively

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy a particular file type such as foo.pbo. These pbo's are scatted in a lot of sub-directories below the source folder. In the destination it is a folder with one sub-directory below it.

I was to use powershell to compare the source folder and sub-directories with files of a .pbo extension to the destination folder, but here is the twist only copy the files that are newer.

I have tried breaking it down, so here was my attempt.

```
$s = Get-ChildItem .\mods -filter *pbo -Recurse
$d = Get-ChildItem .\updates\addons -filter *pbo

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $s -DifferenceObject $d -Property Name, LastWriteTime | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" }
```

How can I copy the files that are found in the compare that are modified in the multiple source directories to a single directory?

All I get in the compare is just the filenames and date modified, I have no path to reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Compare-Object is the wrong tool for this. It compares the existence of properties - you have no way of specifying that it should compare the dates.

I suggest iterating over each source object with a foreach loop and checking if it needs to be copied.

```
$s = Get-ChildItem .\source -Filter *.txt -Recurse
$d = Get-ChildItem .\dest -Filter *.txt

foreach ($file in $s) {
    $targetFile = $d | where Name -eq $file.Name

    # this copies files which do not exist in the target
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -gt $targetFile.LastWriteTime) {
        Copy-Item $file.FullName .\dest
    }

    # this copies only files which exist in the target
    if ($targetFile -and $file.LastWriteTime -gt $targetFile.LastWriteTime) {
        Copy-Item $file.FullName .\dest
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very easy to follow script, and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `Compare-Object` is working properly the data you seek is in `InputObject` note property. At the end of your `Where-Object` pipe into `Select-Object`

```
Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
```

That will return System.IO.FileInfo objects just like `Get-ChildItem` that you can do with what you please.

Answer (score 0):

```
$old_files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\old_files"
$new_files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\new_files"

foreach($file in $new_files){
    if($old_files.Name.Contains($file.Name)){}
    else {
        Copy-Item $file.FullName "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\new_addition"
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.